# Frames border does not move

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, sprite-kit, layer

I'm trying to build a simple game for the exercise sake and cannot figure out why the frame's border is not moving when everything else is.

[image: Start position]
[image: End position]

When I reach the last pillar and move a bit to the right the game ends. This is somehow because the frames border does not move when the goat and pillars does.

I have three layers which is SKNode's. One called _mainLayer, second called _playerLayer and third called _squareLayer. _mainLayer contains _playerLayer and _squareLayer.

When I move the screen this code is being used:

```
-(void)moveScreen {
    _xMoved += 100;

    SKAction *move = [SKAction moveByX:-100 y:0 duration:0.5];
    [_squareLayer runAction:move];
    [_playerLayer runAction:move];
}
```

I have tried to use [_mainLayer runAction:move] instead of the two other calls but then the gameover screen is not moving along which is added in directly into the scene class (the "self").

```
_gameOverScreen = [[EndScene alloc] init];
_gameOverScreen.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 2);
_gameOverScreen.gameOver.size = CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, _gameOverScreen.gameOver.size.height / 2);
[self addChild:_gameOverScreen];
```

The gameover screen is a SKNode class I made myself.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What needs to happen to cause the game to end?

Comment: When the the goat (the player) hits the frame of the screen on any side of the screen the game should end. The problem is that if i get to the second third (last) pilar like on the second image the game ends. I move the _playerLayer and _squareLayer -100 on the x-axis when hitting a new pilar but somehow the frame's border won't move too so the game ends, seen on the second image, when hitting the third pilar. When that is said I figured a work around solution which I will post in a second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem.

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {
// If the goat didn't get on top of a platform
[_playerLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"Goat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(_xMoved, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height), node.position)) {
        _gameOverScreen.numberScore = _score;
        [_gameOverScreen testNewScore:_score];

        [_scoreLabel removeFromParent];
        _gameOverScreen.hidden = NO;
        _gameOver = YES;
    }
}];
```

}

By making a new CGRect that simulates the screen moving I got it to work. But why this (the code below) won't work I don't know.

```
-(void)didSimulatePhysics {
// If the goat didn't get on top of a platform
[_playerLayer enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"Goat" usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(self.frame, node.position)) {
        _gameOverScreen.numberScore = _score;
        [_gameOverScreen testNewScore:_score];

        [_scoreLabel removeFromParent];
        _gameOverScreen.hidden = NO;
        _gameOver = YES;
    }
}];
```

}